# Want to multiply values in table of, Simple and Compund Interest: In javascript

Tags: javascript

Table that needs multiplied:

[image: 1]

I tried getting element by ID, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selectors to locate rows and columns in the table:

```js
const
  currency = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }),
  simpleInterest = (p, t, r) => p + (p * (r * t)),
  compoundInterest = (p, t, r, n) => p * ((1 + (r / n)) ** (n * t));

const
  p = parseInt(document
    .querySelector('table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)')
    .innerText
    .replace(/^\$/, ''), 10),
  t = parseInt(document
    .querySelector('table tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2)')
    .innerText
    .replace(/\s*years$/, ''), 10),
  r = parseInt(document
    .querySelector('table tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)')
    .innerText
    .replace(/%$/, ''), 10) * 0.01,
  n = 1; // number times interest applied per time period

document
  .querySelector('table tfoot tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)')
  .innerText = `${currency.format(simpleInterest(p, t, r))}`;
document
  .querySelector('table tfoot tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)')
  .innerText = `${currency.format(compoundInterest(p, t, r, n))}`;
```

```css
table, th, td { border: thin solid black; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Parameter</th><th>Value</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Principal</td><td>$3000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Annual Interest Rate</td><td>6%</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Period</td><td>5 years</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td>Simple Interest</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Compound Interest</td><td></td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Table API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement#instance_properties):

```js
const
  currency = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }),
  simpleInterest = (p, t, r) => p + (p * (r * t)),
  compoundInterest = (p, t, r, n) => p * ((1 + (r / n)) ** (n * t)),
  table = document.querySelector('table');

const
  p = parseInt(table.tBodies[0].rows[0].cells[1].innerText.replace(/^\$/, ''), 10),
  t = parseInt(table.tBodies[0].rows[2].cells[1].innerText.replace(/\s*years$/, ''), 10),
  r = parseInt(table.tBodies[0].rows[1].cells[1].innerText.replace(/%$/, ''), 10) * 0.01,
  n = 1; // number times interest applied per time period

table.tFoot.rows[0].cells[1].innerText = `${currency.format(simpleInterest(p, t, r))}`;
table.tFoot.rows[1].cells[1].innerText = `${currency.format(compoundInterest(p, t, r, n))}`;
```

```css
table, th, td { border: thin solid black; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Parameter</th><th>Value</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Principal</td><td>$3000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Annual Interest Rate</td><td>6%</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Period</td><td>5 years</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td>Simple Interest</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Compound Interest</td><td></td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```